# Problem with auto update last version of react based web application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I developed react based web application and release it. Now I tried to add some feature to app and update that , I noticed that the new version doesn't update on browser. 
I was tried this on my xampp and The app was simply updated. On my server,

1) Like xampp, I'm serving application build (created by "npm run build") on apache

2) I have HTTPS on It.

3) also "serviceWorker.unregister()" to disable PWA.

But I'm still have update problem.

I really appreciate your help. Also sorry about my English.

Comment: Did you tried to check your website in browser's incognito mode? It's just to make sure that caching is not culprit here. :)

Comment: Yes. I tried. Everything's fine in incognito mode.